# Most efficient way to write big data structures to a file

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, file-writing

Let's say you have an algebraic data type, and you work with huge data structures, would it be more efficient to write a writing function like:

```ml
val writer: out_channel -> mygadttype -> unit
```

That recursively visits the algebraic data type and writes every node, or something like:

```
val print: Format.formatter -> mygadttype -> unit
```

And then use `Format.asprintf` to write into a string and then write that string to the file.

I dont't have an estimation on how big the data structure will be, but performance wise (and memory wise?), which would be more efficient? The goal is for the result to be human readable so no marshalling

Comment: I'd say that depends entirely on how it will be used. Whether it should be human- or machine readable, and if there's any other format restrictions. You could just use [`Marshal`](https://ocaml.org/api/Marshal.html) to dump it more or less directly from memory into a file. Very efficient, but not very portable.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more precise, it should be human readable. I don't see what you mean by format restrictions. My goal is to simply print it in a basic manner, just as a long string, but I'm not sure whether making many calls to ```print_endline``` is more efficient or not than making one call with one huge string (but making many calls to ```Format.asprintf``` to build the string)

Comment: You can always try both and benchmark, right? If you have your huge type already, it should not be much work to test both options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print directly to the file with `Format` by using `Format.formatter_of_out_channel`. It is unclear if the overhead of `Format` will matter without more information or benchmarking.